# grpc-java use in android

Tags: android, grpc

I use

```
protoc -I examples/src/main/proto -I examples/build/extracted-protos/main --java_out=examples/build/generated-sources/main --java_plugin_out=examples/build/generated-sources/main --plugin=protoc-gen-java_plugin=compiler/build/binaries/java_pluginExecutable/java_plugin examples/src/main/proto/route_guide.proto
```

generateing code.

and when I modified the Android demo for this proto file, run `./gradlew installDebug`  I get a problem:

```
no suitable constructor found for HelloRequest()
            HelloRequest message = new HelloRequest();
                                   ^
    constructor HelloRequest.HelloRequest(CodedInputStream,ExtensionRegistryLite) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor HelloRequest.HelloRequest(Builder) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: You need to show some code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it：

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-java_rpc=compiler/build/binaries/java_pluginExecutable/java_plugin --java_rpc_out=nano=true:"examples/build/generated-sources/main/" --proto_path="examples/src/main/proto/" --javanano_out=ignore_services=true:"examples/build/generated-sources/main/" "examples/src/main/proto/helloworld.proto"
```